# How to retrieve the class of a generic type

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic methode like this one:

```
public class ClassName {
    public <T> List<T> methodeName(String path)
        throws FileNotFoundException {
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(path), ',', '\"');

    HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy<T> strat = new HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy<T>();

    strat.setType(T.class);
```

In the last line (`T.class`) eclipse is showing me this synthax-error
`Illegal class literal for the type parameter T`.

A solution like this one proposed here:
[Java generics - retrieve type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670044/java-generics-retrieve-type) won't help me. The methode `getClass()` would only return the current class.

I'm new to generics but I'm sure there is a simple answer for this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simple answer is: you have to pass a `Class<T>` argument to the method.

```
public <T> List<T> methodeName(String path, Class<T> clazz) throws FileNotFoundException {
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(path), ',', '\"');

    HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy<T> strat = 
        new HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy<T>();
    strat.setType(clazz);
}

...

ClassName cn = new ClassName();
List<Foo> foos = cn.methodeName(somePath, Foo.class);
```

Comment: How to initialize this Class<T> object ?

Comment: Thx, it's working! But shouldn't there be a way to get the class from the <T> ? I mean do I really have to change the signature of the methode to accomplish this ?

Comment: Yes, you must change the method signature. If there was a way, the `HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy` parameterized class would use it, and you wouldn't have to call `setType(clazz)`.